# Alternative method of labeling divs

Tags: jquery, html

Can I label my divs in another way to achieve what I'm trying to do here. I have this main div called errors that'll display all error messages. Problem is, my forms input areas and other instruction text need to go in between because the error messages and text need to appear below them. When I do a `$('#errors div').empty();` all the instruction text and everthing else gets cleared, because its all under `<div id="errors">` Any alternate way of labeling these 3 divs (eUname, ePwd, eMail) so its still under the label "errors"?

```
<div id="form">
  <div id="errors">
     //Input field and other instruction text goes here with its own id
  <div id="eUname"></div>
    //Input field and other instruction text goes here with its own id
  <div id="ePwd"></div>
    //Input field and other instruction text goes here with its own id
  <div id="eMail"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Something like:

```
<div id="errors" id="eUname" ></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to be using `class="error"` on all your error divs.

```
<div id="form">
    <div class="error" id="eUname">Error here</div>
    <div class="error" id="ePwd">Error here</div>
</div>
```

This means you can use jQuery like so:

```
$('.error').empty();
```

On a related note, you may consider going through some of the tutorials at [htmlDog](http://htmldog.com/)

Comment: you could also use the class on the parent element and just $('.error div').empty()

Comment: wait wait wait @rlemon .error div:empty is perfectly valid as per css3 selectors ,eek i thought the .empty was to select the empty element .. my bad!! >_< , jQuery why u confuse ?

Comment: @rlemon Actually, I think that causes the same problem the OP had originally. His instructional/hinting text is also in divs, which would then be inside the "errors" div.

Comment: ahhh so the magical `>` direct child selector would be used. `$('.error > div')` should do the trick no?

Comment: It depends on where his instructional divs are. They're not shown in the original source example, so we just don't know.

Comment: Something like this `<div class="errors eUname"></div>`. Nevermind this does not work.

Comment: My instructional divs are within the errors divs (right now), below the input areas.

Comment: @Norman you can have multiple class names on a single element in HTML, however each element can only contain **one** ID and with that said no other element on the same page (within the same document rather) can contain that same ID. This is why we use classes for styling objects rather that ID's

Comment: Right... Rayan's solution did the job. Thanks to all.